# How to print stack trace in custom exception?

Tags: java, logging

I define a custom exception like so  :

```
package source.exception;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class ValidationException extends Exception
{
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("source.exception.ValidationException");

    public ValidationException(String message)
    {
        super(message);
        ValidationException e = new ValidationException();
        logger.error("Exception : {}" , e);
    }
}
```

In the main program I use this exception like so  :

```
public void readFile(String path) throws ValidationException
    {
        logger.debug("Input file path = {}" , path);
        try
        {
            if(validatePath(path))
            {
                mathExpressionReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ValidationException("Your file dose not exist!");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            logger.error("Exception {} has occurred" , ex);
        }
    }
```

Now I don't know how to print stack trace when validatePath fail(means if statement become false)  .Can anyone help me to print stack trace in custom exception?

Comment: `ValidationException e = new ValidationException(); logger.error("Exception : {}" , e);` - what's this meant to do?

Comment: @ immibis yes.but when I define this statment in ValidationException class give me an error . In readFile() method I want to stop the running if validate Path is false and then print stack tarce in file with logback

Comment: Why are you logging in the exception constructor?! Maybe you mean `logger.error("Error", this)`?

Comment: @George Simms In readFile() method I want to stop the program running by define custom exception and throws in method body then print stack trace with logback but I don't know how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Why not just using `e.printStackTrace()`?

```
public class ValidationException extends Exception
{
    public ValidationException(String message)
    {
        super(message);
    }
}

public void readFile(String path) throws ValidationException
{
    logger.debug("Input file path = {}" , path);
    try
    {
        if(validatePath(path))
        {
            mathExpressionReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ValidationException("Your file dose not exist!");
        }
    } catch (ValidationException e) {
        // This will print the stack trace.
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: where do I use try block?In readFile() method?I am new in java .